# fp16 inference on cpu Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, eval, cpu, half-precision-float

I have a `pretrained pytorch` model I want to inference on `fp16` instead of `fp32`, I have already tried this while using the `gpu` but when I try it on `cpu` I get:
`"sum_cpu" not implemented for 'Half' torch`.
any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, a lot of CPU-based operations in Pytorch are not implemented to support FP16; instead, it's NVIDIA GPUs that have hardware support for FP16(e.g. tensor cores in Turing arch GPU) and PyTorch followed up since CUDA 7.0(ish). To accelerate inference on CPU by quantization to FP16, you may wanna try torch.bfloat16 dtype(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/23509).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Intel's CPU you could try [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). It allows you to convert your model into Intermediate Representation (IR) and then run on the CPU with the FP16 support. I cannot guarantee your model is convertible (it depends on whether you have fancy custom layers) but it's worth giving it a try. You can find a full tutorial on how to convert the PyTorch model [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/102-pytorch-onnx-to-openvino).
Some snippets below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[pytorch,onnx]
```

**Save your model to ONNX**

OpenVINO cannot convert PyTorch model directly for now but it can do it with ONNX model. This sample code assumes the model is for computer vision.

```
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH)
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "model.onnx", opset_version=11)
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert ONNX model**

The Model Optimizer is a command line tool which comes from OpenVINO Development Package so be sure you have installed it. It converts the ONNX model to IR, which is a default format for OpenVINO. It also changes the precision to FP16. Run in command line:

```
mo --input_model "model.onnx" --input_shape "[1,3, 224, 224]" --mean_values="[123.675, 116.28 , 103.53]" --scale_values="[58.395, 57.12 , 57.375]" --data_type FP16 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference on the CPU**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device e.g. CPU.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="CPU")

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.

Comment: Will this work also if model is exported via `dyamic_axes` argument as well?

Comment: I'm not an expert in PyTorch but I understand you mean something like dynamic shapes in OpenVINO. It means the network is resized automatically to fit every input. However, it's a very new feature and it only works if your input is not very long. You can read about it here: https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_OV_UG_DynamicShapes.html and try it here: https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/211-speech-to-text/211-speech-to-text.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

Check out this documentation - https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-pytorch/latest/tutorials/features/amp.html.
Intel Extension for PyTorch support Auto Mixed Precision feature for CPUs.
In code, we need to change to torch.cpu.amp.autocast() instead of torch.autocast(device_name="cpu"). torch.cpu.amp supports BFloat16 data type.